# Highcharts: how to add legend after chart creation?

Tags: highcharts

I would like to add a legend dynamically after chart creation.
This legend doesnt have any relation with a series/point, so I dont want to put it into my chart data.
I want to have this legend to implement its click myself.
I know how to handle legend click events. 
My question is how to add a new legend to legendsTable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case when your legend is not realted with chart, why you cannot use any html objects with customised CSS styles?

Comment: Exactly, this legend is not related with my chart. I also thought to create html objects and append to legend table, but one legend item contains really detailed html objects. And, it is also required to give its position manually to legend.

Comment: Have you any mockup of this?

Comment: Sure. <g><g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(8,3)"><text x="21" y="15" style="color:#CCC;font-size:12px;cursor:pointer;fill:#CCC;" text-anchor="start" zIndex="2"><tspan x="21">MY CUSTOM LEGEND</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" rx="2" ry="2" zIndex="3" fill="#DDDF0D"></rect></g></g></g>

Comment: I need an image and description what your legend should do.

Comment: My legend will be used for SELECT/DESELECT ALL button.

Comment: Please prepare any mockup.